# What comparison operators are more processor efficient: <, <=, != or ==?

Tags: javascript, php, performance, operators

I have the choice between types of comparison operations, please put them in the order of efficiency for the processor starting with the most efficient:

```
if (x == 1)

if (x != 0)

if (x < 2)

if (x <= 3)
```

Often I am faced with case where I can use any of them I choose for the same outcome...

This is something I've always wanted to know and probably some other people want to know it too. Also, does it vary for different programming languages or not?

*Edit: Thanks for the information. Because they are apparently all the same efficiency this means I can use more > or < type operators in order to catch glitches better!*

Comment: Ever heard about premature optimization? Your question would qualify for an award in this category...

Comment: They all are one processor instruction. No difference.

Comment: They are *not* one processor instruction in JavaScript...

Comment: @RobW I know what you are saying but given I can use any of them and it requires the same effort to type either one of them surely this would fall under "pedantic programming style" rather than premature optimisation :)

Comment: Use the one that makes most sense to a reader of your code.

Comment: @zmbq yes if they are all blazingly fast then that would seem to make sense hmmm.....code readability

Comment: Why waste you time on micro-optimisation. If you are so concerned with performance chose a compiled language

Comment: @EdHeal Hehe yes or I can type the machine code maybe :)

Comment: @AmyNeville - Perhps Java would be a comprimise

Comment: It's a very good question. It shows you are thinking about your work and curious, and not just doing what someone told you to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, any of them is more efficient than the others. This is because on most CPUs, they map to specialized opcodes, whose execution is handled by the very same physical unit, in slightly different configurations. Using a non-existent but very simple to understand assembly syntax, each branch (`if` condition) might translate to:

```
if (x == 1)
    test = x - 1
    branch_equal_zero test

if (x != 0)
    test = 0
    branch_non_equal_zero test

if (x < 2)
    test = x - 2
    branch_lower_than_zero test

if (x <= 3)
    test = x - 3
    branch_lower_or_equal_to_zero test
```

As you can see, comparing to zero (regardless of the comparision)  *might* be faster because there is no subtraction involved -- but faster of such a tiny fraction of second you *might* notice it only under extremely heavy load.

Even if we are speaking of interpreted languages (PHP and JS), the answer does not change, because all operators are directly mapped to the underlying native comparisions by the interpreters. Let alone any type cast or intermediate conversion that might take place.

Comment: interesting because I always suspected the < type operators were slightly slower. But then this is micro optimisation just wondered.

Comment: Nothing that would be worth the effort of profiling and checking.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "They are all the same", because, at the basic level, they are all the same. Also, they are all so blazingly fast, you won't notice the difference anyway.

I can see how one may be quicker than the other - CPUs tend to reorder instructions and predict branches - so in specific cases there may be a difference.

However, none if these cases applies to anything you do in JavaScript. In JavaScript you can be very certain they are all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Let's put it differently, starting from the higher level.
Javascript and PHP, both of them are high level language, and so won't use CPU directly but over many processes already thought to optimize what you write. In Javascript that "process" is called Javascript Engine. In PHP it is the interpreter itself. Don't misunderstand me, they are thought to do their work leaving "a bit" of care on optimization.

So in the end the real way to optimize this kind of operation would be to find a real big issue in PHP or Javascript Engine itself.

Now let's face the lowest aspect of these operators. A modern CPU has 3.2GHz (or even more) clock speed. So, it would mean 3200000000 operations per second, which is a huge number. Suppose those operation (which in the end are almost all the same) use 2 or 3 ticks. it would take you about 10^9 operators to notice a significative difference.

Comment: It was just out of example :)