# How comparison operator utilizes CPU cycle in programming

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, coding-style, software-design, instruction-set

If I have following conditions then which comparison condition executes fast(in terms of CPU cycles and time):

```
if(1 < 2)

if(1 < 100)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073836/what-comparison-operators-are-more-processor-efficient-or

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no dynamic values in your example, only constants, so compiler (either AOT or JIT one) could optimize out both conditions and compiled code would not contain `if`s. Thus no difference between these conditions.

Even if there were dynamic values, both conditions would have the same speed. Because comparison to a value is fast operation, comparison to 2 either to 1000 will have the same time.

E.g. for x86 64-bit. `if (value < 2)` would translate into something like:

```
cmp rax, 2
jl condition_succeded_label
```

From [Instruction latencies and throughput for AMD and Intel x86 processors](https://gmplib.org/%7Etege/x86-timing.pdf) by Torbjörn Granlund, Intel/AMD CPUs have 1 cycle latency for `CMP` instruction (L64 below), and each core of modern Intel/AMD CPUs can do up to 4 `CMP` instructions in parallel (T64, a throughput, below). Regardless of the constant operand, either 2 or 1000.
[image: CMP thouthput]

What may differ is branch misprediction, when CPU predicts wrong branch, it may cost 10-20 cycles ([reference from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor)) of CPU or more (depending on CPU model, data in cache, memory speed). While comparison itself takes 0.25-1 cycles as in the table above.

Comment: Thanks, provided references are helpful.